# Cloud Composer - Get google user

Tags: google-cloud-composer

There is a way to get the google account name running the DAGs from the DAG definition?
This will be very helpful to track which users was running the DAGs.

I'm only see :

```
unixname    --> always airflow
owner       --> fixed in the dag definition
```

Regards
Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

Possible as DAGs in Composer are essentially GCS objects. The [GCS object GET](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) API does tell you who uploads that object. So here's one possible way of getting owner info:

1. Define a function user_lookup() in your DAG definition.
2. The implementation of user_look() consists of the following steps: a) gets the current file path (e.g., os.path.basename(__file__)); b) based on how Composer GCS objects are mapped locally, determines the corresponding GCS object path (e.g., gs://{your-bucket}/object); c) reads GCS object details and returns object.owner.
3. In your DAG definition, set owner=user_lookup().

Let us know whether the above works for you.